# Delete all files except filenames with specific string

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

I have 1000's of files like `TOP_QUERIES-abc.com.au.csv`,`TOP_QUERIES-www.abc.com.au.csv`, `TOP_QUERIES-m.lmn.com.au.csv`, `TOP_QUERIES-blog.com.au.csv`and `get-files.php`

Is it possible to delete all the .csv files from a folder except for files starting with `blog.` ,`m.` , `www`, and `.php` from the folder?

I know its possible in php but how can I achieve in batch file?

Comment: Warning... the Revision for efficiency code make the oposite thing... Delete all the Excluded files!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetdir=U:\destdir"
SET "exclude=blog. m. www."
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%targetdir%\*.csv" '
 ) DO (
 ECHO %%a | findstr /B /L "%exclude%" >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO(DEL "%targetdir%\%%a"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This should get the task done for you. You would need to change the setting of `targetdir` to suit your circumstances.

The required DEL commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(DEL` to `DEL` to actually delete the files.

The `.php` files are excluded because they don't match the `*.csv` filename - or did you want to not-delete files starting `.php`? If so, simply add `.php` into the `exclude` variable...

---

Revision for efficiency:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetdir=U:\destdir"
SET "exclude=blog. m. www."
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%targetdir%\*.csv" ^| findstr /B /L "%exclude%"'
 ) DO (ECHO(DEL "%targetdir%\%%a"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Um - you state "all files" and you also state "all the .csv files" please clarify...

Comment: Thanks for your program @Magoo. By "all files " i meant all `.csv` files only.

Comment: `@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetdir=C:\Users\user\Desktop\New"
SET "exclude=blog. m. www."
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%targetdir%\*.csv" '
 ) DO (
 ECHO %%a | findstr /B /L "%exclude%" >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 DEL "%targetdir%\%%a"
GOTO :EOF`

I added this code but it does not delete any thing! What is my mistake?

Comment: Also when i echo ed it gave me list of all the programs including the ones which have to be excluded

Comment: Whoa, Neddy! Or Penny - whatever. The entire purpose of the `ECHO(` is to ensure that the files **don't** get deleted, in case of an error - and "a list of all *programs*? including those excluded" is an error. We have to fix that first. Once we have the correct file list, **only then** do we move on to the actual deletion.

Comment: "list of all the files* " i meant ! My Bad!

Comment: Oh i got my mistake ! Since the filename starts with `TOP_QUERIES-`  i need to change `SET "exclude=blog. m. www."` to `SET "exclude=TOP_QUERIES-blog. TOP_QUERIES-m. TOP_QUERIES-www."`

Comment: Problem solvered? Job done, then. In you listing in the comments, you've also omitted the closing-parenthesis line before the `goto :eof`. The `echo` statement is quite bizarre. The character following the `o` in `echo` is important. Traditionally, it's a space, but it may be other. Of these, `(` is most flexible because `echo(%var%` where `var` is a variable with no value will produce a newline whereas `echo %var%` will report `echo is on/off`. The `(` in `echo(` plays no part whatever in parenthesis-counting for nested conditionals. Welcome to the crazy world of the world's kookiest language

Comment: Oh yes i forgot to add here! Though added in my program. Yes very new to batch scripting but its very exciting it does wonders. Its fun learning

Comment: Why put the FINDSTR within the DO clause? It would be more efficient to pipe the DIR /B result into FINDSTR within your IN() clause.

Comment: @dbenham : undoubtedly. Fixed.